# Proof by contradiction for "OR" statements.

Tags: logic

If you are trying to prove $x \to y \ \ \text{or} \ \ z$, how do you prove by contradiction? Do you split into two cases, or do you assume both are false?

Comment: Is it $(x \to y) \vee z$ OR $x \to (y \vee z)$?

Comment: You assume both are false.

Comment: If you mean $x\to(y\lor z)$, note that the negation of $y\lor z$ is $\neg y\land\neg z$, so for a proof by contradiction you would that $x$ is true and both $y$ and $z$ are false; for a proof of the contrapositive you would assume that $y$ and $z$ are false and try to show that $x$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

To prove by contradiction that a statement of the form "$x \to y$"  is true, you assume the statement  "$x \ \ \text{and} \ \ \text{not} \ \ y$". So if you have a statement of the form "$x \to y \ \ \text{or} \ \ z$" and you want to prove it by contradiction, you start by assuming the statement $$x \ \ \text{and} \ \ (\text{not} \ \ (y \ \ \text{or} \ \ z)),$$ which is logically equivalent to $$x \ \ \text{and} \ \ (( \text{not} \ \ y )\ \ \text{and} \ \ (\text{not} \ \ z)).$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to  prove $x\implies y\lor z$ by contradiction:

$1) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~\neg [x\implies y \lor z]~~~$ (Assume)

$~\vdots$

$n) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~p \land \neg p~~~$  (Obtain a contradiction. Alternatively, obtain $p \iff  \neg p$)

$n+1) ~~~~~~\neg\neg [x\implies y \lor z]~~~$ (Discharge, 1, n)

$n+2) ~~~~~x\implies y \lor z~~~$ (Elim $\neg \neg$, n+1)

Here is another way:

$1) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~x~~~$ (Assume)

$2) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\neg [y \lor z]~~~$  (Assume)

$~\vdots$

$n) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~p \land \neg p~~~$  (Obtain a contradiction. Alternatively, obtain $p \iff  \neg p$)

$n+1)~~~~~ \neg \neg [y \lor z]~~~$  (Discharge, 2, n)

$n+2) ~~~~~y\lor z~~~$ (Elim $\neg \neg$, n+1)

$n+3) ~~~~~x\implies y\lor z~~~$ (Discharge, 1, n+2)